# Why couldn't Bell "save" Artemis at the end of the movie "Arrow of the Orion"?

Tags: danmachi

With the Arrow of Orion and his knife, Bell was able to free Artemis from that shell and we can also see that she was still alive at that point.

So why did he still have to kill her?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

She was still connected to that monster and to prevent Antares from being able to use her powers again even if it was defeated

Comment: But couldn't Bell just physically sever that connection by dragging her out (without killing her) or is it that the Antares is able to use that power without a physical connection to Artemis? That doesn't make sense for me though, as there would have been no reason why she was even held inside that shell.